# Comparing values in a DataGridView against MySQL if they share the same ID

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to compare a value in one column in a DataGridView against a  column in a MySQL Table using an "ID". The way I'm approaching this as the program cycles through the DataGridView, it will pull up the amount of stock in MySQL, put it into a textbox and compare it to the amount in the DataGridView. If the number is bigger in the DataGridView, a text box will say: "Stock falls below 0". If the number is bigger in the MySQL table, the text box will say "Stock remains above or equals 0" instead.

I'll highlight the exact line below but when I try to run the code, this error pops up:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()'

I'm not sure why this error appearing. I use very similar code in other parts of my project with no complaints.

This is my attempt:

```
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "SELECT Quantity FROM `database`.`stockroom` WHERE `ID`='@Stock'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            Sum_Quantity.Text = READER.GetString("Quantity") 'Error appears here

     If Sum_Quantity.Text >= DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString() Then 'IF STOCK REMAINS ABOVE OR EQUAL TO 0
            Sum_Outcome.Text = "Stock remains above or equals 0"
     ElseIf Sum_Result.Text <= DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString() Then 'IF STOCK REACHES BELOW 0
            Sum_Outcome.Text = "Stock falls below 0"
     End If
Next
```

Comment: I'd load a datatable from MySQL, then all the comparisons could be done and shown in the grid.. The one textbox approach could be a bit laborious

Comment: Ah alright. I'll try changing that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your connection.
2. Swap your `ExecuteReader` call for `ExecuteScalar` and capture it into an integer - `Dim qty = Convert.ToInt32(COMMAND.ExecuteScalar())`
3. Don't compare strings using `>=` and `<=` - [it will go wrong](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ck2Gbg) because `"10"` is less than `"2"` - take the quantity from the grid as an integer, and compare it with the integer from the database

The code as you have it there is almost pointless because if will loop, say, 100 roows, change the textbox 100 times so fast that you'll only see the last change...

Were it my problem I'd maybe do it more like this:

```
'imagine your grid is based on a datatable with the order info in
dt.Rows.Add("Apples", 1)
dt.Rows.Add("Pears", 2)
dt.Rows.Add("Bananas", 4)

'show the order in the grid
datagridviewX.DataSource = dt
```

So imagine that's where you've got to now, above. It would help us if the DGV was looking at a table that had a couple more columns:

```
'add another columns to the table to hold the stock quantity and message
dt.Columns.Add("Stock", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Determination").Expression = "IIF([Quantity]>[Stock],'Not enough stock','Can fulfil this order')"
```

Then when we want to analyze the order for being able to supply it:

```
'loop over the table looking up the stock quants
Using cmd as New MySqlCommand("SELECT Quantity FROM Stock WHERE ID = @id", "conn str here")
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "dummy value")
  cmd.Connection.Open()
  For Each ro as DataRow in dt.Rows
    cmd.Parameters("@id").Value = ro("Name").ToString()
    ro("Stock") = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
  Next ro
End Using
```

So that code will pull the stock amounts for all the items in the grid and stash it in the Stock column. Separately an Expression on a string column gives a commentary on if there is enough stock or not.

Comment: At the moment the textbox is a placement holder for another piece of code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I added a bit on how you might look stuff up and use the datagrid to show

Comment: Thank you for the expansion and explanation. Your way seems to be a lot less... awkward than mine to say the least. Thanks once again!